# Adding xsl:nil to XElement

Tags: c#, xml, null, xelement

This is really starting to wind me up. I've tried searching all over the net with this but it seems people only want to consume XML files, not build them :S. I'm building an XML file which needs to be compliant with an .xsd referencing the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace.

One of the elements in the XSD is a datetime which unfortunately may or may not have a value.
From what I've read, the correct way to achieve this is to use the `nil` attribute, but no matter what I do, the validation just moans at me, saying that

> '' is not a valid value for type 'date'

I've tried:

```
elementName.SetAttributeValue(xmlNamespace + "nil", "true"); //(xmlNamespace = pre-declared NS)
```

and

```
elementName.SetAttributeValue("nil", "true");
```

Alongside everything else I can think of, but I just can't get it to validate.
Unfortunately I also can't just leave it out as the element doesn't have `minOccurs = 0` in the XSD either.

Any ideas?

Comment: thanks for the edit dymanoid, I can never get the code formatting to work.

Comment: I was fighting the same issue last week for hours.  I then discovered I didn't need the namespace.  The namespace was set in the parent.  When I didn't use the namespace in the child I automatically got the child with no namespace.

Comment: What is the XSD for your element? Does it have `nillable="true"`?

Comment: hi Canton - maybe im completely misunderstanding this, but doesn't that namespace allow nil for date?

Comment: @Adamski343 If and only if the XSD has `nillable="true"` IIRC. If you use `xsi:nil="true"` and your XSD doesn't have `nillable="true"`, then that will fail validation

Comment: What is `xmlNamespace`? It should be `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. Re whether it's allowed (as @canton7 suggests), [this explains](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xml-in-a/0596007647/re166.html). Failing that, it's hard to answer without seeing a [mcve].